# Nodejs out of memory on pipe for pdfMake

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Nodejs server that is being used to create about 1200 pdf forms that can be downloaded by a client later. They are being created using pdfmake and then output to a server folder. When I execute the code as written at about 350 documents, Nodejs runs out of memory. I know there must be a better way to save, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

The below method is being called by a map of an array of data from a Mongoose query. The relevant code for creating and saving the form is as follows:

```
const whichForm = certList => {
    certList.map(cert => { 
        if (cert.Cert_Details !== null) {
            switch (cert.GWMA) {
              case 'OA':
              case 'PC':
              // Don't provide reports for Feedlots
                if (cert.Cert_Details.cert_type !== null) {
                   if (cert.Cert_Details.cert_type === 'Irrigation') {
                     createOAReport(cert);
                   }
                }
                break;
             case 'FA':
             // Don't provide reports for Feedlots
               if (cert.Cert_Details.cert_type === 'Irrigation') {
                    createFAReport(cert);
                   }
               break;
               }
         }
    }
}
```

Different File:

```
const PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake/src/printer');
const fs = require('fs');

const createOAReport = data => {
    console.log('PC or OA Cert ', data.Cert_ID);
    // console.log(data);

    let all_meters_maint = [];

    data.Flowmeters.map(flowmeter => {
     // Each Flow meter
     // console.log(`Inside Flowmeter ${flowmeter}`);

      if (flowmeter.Active === true) {
        let fm_maint = [];
        fm_maint.push({
        text: `Meter Serial Number: ${flowmeter.Meter_Details.Serial_num}`
        });
      fm_maint.push({
        text: `Type of Meter: ${flowmeter.Meter_Details.Manufacturer}`
      });
      fm_maint.push({ text: `Units: ${flowmeter.Meter_Details.units}`});
      fm_maint.push({ text: `Factor: ${flowmeter.Meter_Details.factor}`});
      all_meters_maint.push(fm_maint);
    }

    docDefinition.content.push({
      style: 'tableExample',
      table: {
        widths: [200, 200, '*', '*'],
        body: all_meters_maint
      },
      layout: 'noBorders'
    });

    const fonts = {
      Roboto: {
        normal: path.join(__dirname, '../', '/fonts/Roboto- 
        Regular.ttf'),
        bold: path.join(__dirname, '../', '/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
        italics: path.join(__dirname, '../', '/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf'),
        bolditalics: path.join(__dirname, '../', '/fonts/Roboto- 
        MediumItalic.ttf')
        }
    };

  const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
  const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

  // Build file path
  const fullfilePath = path.join(
    __dirname,
    '../',
    '/public/pdffiles/',
    `${data.Cert_ID}.pdf`
  );

  pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullfilePath));
  pdfDoc.end();
};
```

Is there a different way to save the files that don't force them to be in a stream and will not be kept in memory?

Comment: Your code is pretty poorly formatted. Please improve the formatting and styling so it's easier for us to help you. There are also a lot of unknowns with your code. How is this method being called? What is data equal to? Where do you define `all_meters_maint`? etc.

Comment: I updated the code and added more context to hopefully get added help.

Comment: Awesome! Just remember, the more effort you put into writing a high quality question, the better answers you will get. In your code there is still a lot of syntax errors (missing `}` and `)`, etc.). I think I fixed all of those in my answer example. Hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we get to the answer, I'm making one huge assumption based on the information in the question. The question states `create about 1200 pdf forms`. Which means I'm assuming in the function `whichForm` the parameter `certList` is an array of 1200 items. Or should I say 1200 items that will call the `createOAReport` method. You get the idea. I'm assuming the problem is that we are calling that method to create the PDFs 1200 times within that `Array.map` method. Which makes sense I believe given the question and context of the code.

On to the answer. The major problem is you aren't just trying to create 1200 pdfs. You are trying to create 1200 pdfs asynchronously, which of course puts a strain on the system trying to do all of that work all at once. Maybe even more so on a single thread system like Node.js.

The easy hacky solution is to just increase the memory of Node.js. By using the `--max-old-space-size` flag and setting the memory size in MB when running your node command. You can find more information about this at [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/node-js-increase-the-memory-limit-for-your-process). But the short version is a command like `node --max-old-space-size=8192 main.js`. That would increase the memory size of Node.js to 8192 MB or 8 GB.

Few problems with that method. Mainly it's not super scalable. What if someday you have 5000 pdfs you want to create? You'd have to increase that memory size again. And maybe increase the specs on the machine it's being run on.

The second solution, which you could actually probably do with the first solution, is to make this process not asynchronous. Depending on many factors and how optimized the current system is, chances are this will increase the amount of time it takes to create all of these PDFs.

This process is kinda a two step process to code it in. First is to setup your `createOAReport` function to return a promise to indicate when it's done. The second step is to change your `whichForm` function to limit how many items can be running asynchronously at any single point in time.

You will have to of course play around with the system to determine how many items you want to run at one time without overloading the system. Fine-tuning that number is not something I focused on, and of course you could probably increase that number by increasing the memory you give Node.js as well.

And of course, there are TONS of different ways to do this. I have a few ideas of methods that are better than the one I'm going to show here, but are a lot more complicated. The foundational idea of limiting how many items are running at once remains the same tho. You can optimize it to fit your needs.

I've developed systems like this before, but I don't think the way I've done it is the best or cleanest way to do it. But at the end of this question I've attached some sample code for your example trying to illustrate my point.

---

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const MAX_RUNNING_PROMISES = 10; // You will have to play with this number to get it right for your needs

const whichForm = async certList => {
    // If certList is ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    // And we run the following function with MAX_RUNNING_PROMISES = 2
    // array would equal [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
    certList = _.chunk(certList, MAX_RUNNING_PROMISES);
    // Of course you can use something other than Lodash here, but I chose it because it's the first thing that came to mind

    for (let i = 0; i < certList.length; i++) {     
        const certArray = certList[i];

        // The following line will wait until all the promises have been resolved or completed before moving on
        await Promise.all(certArray.map(cert => {
            if (cert.Cert_Details !== null) {
                switch (cert.GWMA) {
                    case 'OA':
                    case 'PC':
                        // Don't provide reports for Feedlots
                        if (cert.Cert_Details.cert_type !== null) {
                            if (cert.Cert_Details.cert_type === 'Irrigation') {
                                return createOAReport(cert);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'FA':
                        // Don't provide reports for Feedlots
                        if (cert.Cert_Details.cert_type === 'Irrigation') {
                            return createFAReport(cert);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Then for your other file. We just have to convert it to return a promise.

```
const PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake/src/printer');
const fs = require('fs');

const createOAReport = data => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('PC or OA Cert ', data.Cert_ID);
        // console.log(data);

        let all_meters_maint = [];

        const flowmeter = data.Flowmeters[0];

        if (flowmeter.Active === true) {
            let fm_maint = [];
            fm_maint.push({
                text: `Meter Serial Number: ${flowmeter.Meter_Details.Serial_num}`
            });
            fm_maint.push({
                text: `Type of Meter: ${flowmeter.Meter_Details.Manufacturer}`
            });
            fm_maint.push({
                text: `Units: ${flowmeter.Meter_Details.units}`
            });
            fm_maint.push({
                text: `Factor: ${flowmeter.Meter_Details.factor}`
            });
            all_meters_maint.push(fm_maint);
        }

        docDefinition.content.push({
            style: 'tableExample',
            table: {
                widths: [200, 200, '*', '*'],
                body: all_meters_maint
            },
            layout: 'noBorders'
        });

        const fonts = {
                Roboto: {
                    normal: path.join(__dirname, '../', '/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'),
                    bold: path.join(__dirname, '../', '/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
                    italics: path.join(__dirname, '../', '/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf'),
                    bolditalics: path.join(__dirname, '../', '/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf')
                }
        };

        const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
        const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

        // Build file path
        const fullfilePath = path.join(
            __dirname,
            '../',
            '/public/pdffiles/',
            `${data.Cert_ID}.pdf`
        );

        pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullfilePath));
        pdfDoc.on('finish', resolve); // This is where we tell it to resolve the promise when it's finished
        pdfDoc.end();
    });
};
```

---

I just realized after getting really far into this answer that my original assumption is incorrect. Since some of those pdfs might be created within the second function and the `data.Flowmeters.map` system. So although I'm not going to demonstrate it, you will have to apply the same ideas I have given throughout this answer to that system as well. For now, I have removed that section and am just using the first item in that array, since it's just an example.

You might want to restructure your code once you have an idea of this and just have one function that handles creating the PDF, and not have as many `.map` method calls all over the place. Abstract the `.map` methods out and keep it separate from the PDF creation process. That way it'd be easier to limit how many PDFs are being created at a single time.

It'd also be a good idea to add in some error handling around all of these processes.

---

**NOTE** I didn't actually test this code at all, so there might be some bugs with it. But the overall ideas and principals still apply.

Comment: Awesome answer, I really appreciate the help, your assumption was correct in the execution of the code and the array of information. I had changed the max memory of Node to allow for the increased size, but that is treating a symptom of a problem and not addressing the problem. I'll take your suggestions and implement it with a promise to try to get a limit on the process and go from there!

Comment: @Heath Of course! One of the better answers I think I've written on this site. So I'm glad it was helpful to you.